# HTML: How to show a list whose size is unknown in advance on a webpage?

Tags: html, arrays, list, struct

I'm like to admit that my knowledge of HTML is very little.

Assume we have a button on our pagepage that calls a javascript function: check().

The check() function withdraws an array (contantly updated) of values, e.g.  string, from a server. If each element of the array has a certain property, e.g. contain a letter "a", then it wants to print those strings on the webpage.

The upperbound of the array size retrieved from the server is known but we do not know in advance how many elements satisfies the condition checked by check().

**Question** how to print the elements found by check() on a HTML file (a webpage).

Let's assume javascrip is in the the HTLM file too.

Comment: What have you tried? We are not here to write code for you.  Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With something like `<div id="destination"></div>` in the HTML as a placeholder, you can use JavaScript to loop through your array of items and insert each one into the HTML with:

```
document.getElementById('destination').innerHTML += '<p>' + myData + '</p>';
```

Comment: thank you very much for the answer. Is there any way to print each value on a separate line?

Comment: It will print on a separate line as is. `<p>` is a block element so each one will print on its own line unless you override this behavior in the style sheet.